# « Tu peux faire l'imbécile » : que veut dire « pouvoir » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Il y a deux semaines, après qu'un adolescent avait appelé Emmanuel Macron « Manu », celui-ci a répliqué ainsi :

> Non, tu es là dans une cérémonie officielle. Tu te comportes comme il faut. Tu **peux** faire l'imbécile, mais aujourd'hui c'est la Marseillaise et le Chant des Partisans. Tu m'appelles *monsieur le président de la République* ou *monsieur*.

Je ne reconnais pas cet usage du verbe *pouvoir*, et je ne réussis pas à l'identifier avec aucun des [sens mentionnés dans le *TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pouvoir). Que veut-il dire dans ce contexte ? En quoi diffère « Tu **peux** faire l'imbécile » de « Tu fais l'imbécile » ?

Également, j'ai lu récemment la pièce *L'École des femmes* de Molière ; dans la première scène de l'acte V, Arnolphe fait référence à « cet ordre que j'ai **pu** vous prescrire », ce qui est un ordre qu'il a bien prescrit à ses interlocuteurs (mais qu'il regrette, à cause d'une conséquence inattendue). Le verbe *pouvoir* sert-il la même fonction dans cet exemple-ci que dans les paroles de Macron ci-dessus ?

Comment: (Et comme toujours, merci d'avance pour toute correction !)

Comment: "Tu peux te permettre (droit donné à lui-même, droit donné à tort du point de vue d'Emmanuel Macron) de faire l'imbécile" pourrait-être une traduction plus explicite. Concernant Molière, sans plus de contexte, c'est "par le passé j'avais le droit de le faire, je pouvais le faire", mais maintenant soit je ne peux plus, soit je regrette de l'avoir fait, ou alors cela peut dire que je ne suis pas sûr de l'avoir fait, mais puisque vous le dites...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

À mon avis "pouvoir" est simplement utilisé ici dans le sens de "avoir beau [faire quelque chose]". D'après le TLFi,

> II.A.3.b) [L'oppos. (valeur concess., en déb. de phrase, le verbe étant souvent accompagné de bien)] Avoir beau. Le wagon enragé peut bien Écraser ma tête coupable (...) Je m'en moque comme de Dieu (Baudel.,Fl. du Mal, 1857, p.189).

C'est donc pour exprimer l'opposition entre deux choses. Ici, Macron dit à l'étudiant que malgré le fait qu'il "fait l'imbécile" ("tu as beau faire l'imbécile"), il doit quand même l'appeler "monsieur le président".

Je ne pense pas que l'usage dans la pièce de Molière est le même. Là c'est juste la présentation d'un fait hypothétique, pour se dédouaner.

Comment: Bien vu. C'est effectivement une possibilité qui ne peut être exclue. Mais il y a une ambiguïté. En effet,  "aujourd'hui" suggère l'opposition d'un cas particulier (aujourd'hui) par rapport à un cas général (les autres jours). Le sens de "avoir le droit" me semble donc à privilégier.

Answer (score 7):

Pouvoir signifie ici *avoir le droit, la permission de*.

Macron a dit à l'adolescent qu'en règle générale, il avait le droit de faire l'imbécile mais que dans ce contexte particulier, la familiarité était plus que malvenue.

La phrase est différente de *tu fais l'imbécile* qui est une simple constatation.

Dans *L'École des femmes*, Le verbe pouvoir a un sens hypothétique:

> *que j'ai pu vous prescrire* = *qu'il m'a été possible de vous prescrire* ou *qu'il est possible que je vous aie prescrit*.

Answer (score 0):

Selon le Wiktionnaire, le verbe pouvoir a plusieurs sens:

1. Il y a d'abord une notion de capacité donc lorsque le sujet peut faire quelque chose c'est qu'il en a la capacité physique ou mentale.
2. Ensuite, il y a une notion de droit, de permission lorsque le sujet peut faire quelque chose car il en a obtenu la permission ou que la loi lui accorde le droit de procéder.
3. Par ailleurs, il peut aussi exprimer une possibilité donc, lorsque le sujet peut faire quelque chose, c'est que cette chose s'offre à lui comme un choix qu'il peut faire (ou non) parmi tant d'autres.

Il y a, bien sûr, plusieurs autres subtilités au verbe pouvoir. Ces dernières sont expliquées en détails dans l'article Wiktionnaire, accessible [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pouvoir).

Answer (score 0):

Je crois que cet usage (celui de Manu) corresponde assez bien au sens suivant (de votre lien au *TLFi*):

> [POUVOIR](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pouvoir)
>
> II. ...
>     A. ...
>   1. ...
>     a) ...
>
> b) [Le suj. désigne une pers., souvent en cont. exclam. ou interr.]
>   **Avoir l'audace de**. Synon. **oser**, daigner, avoir le front* de (littér.).Ah, si tu savais ce qu'il a pu me faire souffrir! (Martin du
>   G.,Thib., Cah. gr., 1922, p.608):
>
> 3. C'est moi qui ai tort, dit-elle; je vous en demande bien pardon. Comment ai-je pu me fâcher d'un mot qui n'était sûrement pas dit pour
>      me faire de la peine? Krüdener,Valérie, 1803, p.22.
>      − Absol. [En
>      cont. exclam. ou interr.] Célestincic: Ma petite fille. Ma petite
>      (...). Elle avait une poupée bleue. Comment, comment a-t-elle pu... Ma
>      petite... Alarica: Le mal court (Audiberti,Mal court, 1947, iii,
>      p.198).
>
> "Tu oses/as l'audace de faire l'imbécile, mais ..."

---

Pour l'usage de M Molière, ce n'est pas le même sens et ne sert pas la même fonction, d'après moi.

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que quand Macron dit "Tu peux faire l'imbécile", il se permet de corriger et de qualifier le reste de ce qu'il dit ainsi: "Enfin, tu n'es pas obligé de faire ce que je dis, mais ne pas le faire serait faire l'imbécile. Comme je suppose que tu ne veux pas faire l'imbécile, j'ai omis et j'omettrai de faire cette précision."

Donc *pouvoir* a le sens indiqué dans la réponse de Jlliagre.

Answer (score 0):

Tu peux le faire = il t’est possible de le faire (que tu en aies le droit ou pas est un autre problème). Macron définit un contexte particulier dans la phrase qui précède. Dans ce contexte, « tu peux pas ». Son expresssion est très rapide mais claire. On serait plutôt dans le 
II. ...
A. ...
1. ...
a) ..
alpha)

Quant à Molière, il serait tentant de rapprocher l’usage, pour avouer un acte passé et regretté. Paraphrasant, ‘il est possible, il se peut que je l’ai fait [dans un certain contexte] mais maintenant je ne le ferais pas’